# Perl convert a filehandle in-place/streaming from cp1252 to utf-8?

Tags: perl, utf-8

I have a filehandle open on a file with cp1252 characters in it. I want to give that open filehandle to a library that expects raw utf8 bytes, it's going to send those over the network.

The naive way to do it would be to write the file out to a second file with the right encoding, and give the second filehandle to the library:

```
use Fcntl qw/SEEK_SET/;

open my $fh_1252, "<:encoding(cp1252)", "1252.txt" || die $!;

open my $fh_utf8, "+>:encoding(utf8)", "utf8.txt"  || die $!;

while (<$fh_1252>){ print $fh_utf8 $_ };

seek($fh_utf8, 0, SEEK_SET);

# now give $fh_utf8 to the library for transmission
```

That seems like a bunch of extra work.  Is there a way to just stream it?  I know I could use IO::Scalar to remove the need to write to disk, but I'd still have to read the whole thing into memory.  It seems like there's a way to stream it with a pipeline, but I'm not thinking of a way to do that right now.

Comment: Are you talking about perl library or non perl library/propgram? Could you name your OS (unix/windows)?

Comment: Note: `open ..., "1252.txt" || die $!;` means `open ..., ("1252.txt" || die $!);` (which never dies). You want `open ..., "1252.txt" or die $!;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own conversion module for `PerlIO` and use it with `:via(MODULE)`. Your module can pass the data through `Text::Iconv` to convert from one charset to another.

This way is described in the manual `PerlIO::via(3pm)`. In short, you will need to create your own module, e.g. `PerlIO::via::Example`—that is, you make `PerlIO/via` directory and put `Example.pm` there, with the following content:

```
package PerlIO::via::Example;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Iconv;
my $converter = Text::Iconv->new("windows-1252", "utf-8");

sub PUSHED
{
    my ($class, $mode, $fh) = @_;
    # When writing we buffer the data
    my $buf = '';
    return bless \$buf, $class;
}

sub FILL
{
    my ($obj, $fh) = @_;
    my $line = <$fh>;
    return (defined $line) ? 'converted: ' . $converter->convert($line) : undef;
    # 'converted: ' is added here for debugging purposes
}

sub WRITE
{
    my ($obj,$buf,$fh) = @_;
    $$obj .= $buf; # we do nothing here
    return length($buf);
}

sub FLUSH
{
    my ($obj, $fh) = @_;
    print $fh $$obj or return -1;
    $$obj = '';
    return 0;
}

1;
```

and then use it in `open` like here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PerlIO::via::Example;

open(my $fh, "<:via(Example)", "input.txt");
while (<$fh>) {
    print;
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: This looked like it was going to work, but the engineer working on this problem responded: "His answer would work if we were dealing with a file on the local filesystem (in his example, 'input.txt'), but we just get an already open filehandle back from mogilefs so we can't pass it through the new PerlIO module that he outlines."  Awesome answer, though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use external program to convert input file. See `perldoc -f open` for details.

```
open( my $ft, '-|' "iconf -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 1252.txt") || die $!;
```

P.S. There are simpler solutions for perl libraries.  The above is most general IMHO.